# MongoDB data storage strategy

Tags: node.js, mongodb, query-optimization, data-modeling

I'm using MongoDB and I'm quiet new to it, so I'd like your help on how to model my data. What is the best efficient way?

Here is my use case.

Let's say I have three income sources, named Income1, Income2, Income3. Tomorrow they might be 4 or 20. Each new Income source will suppose new integration to be implemented.

Let's say I have ten users, named User1, User2... User10. Tomorrow they might be 1000. (I hope ;-)). Here, no integration needed for a new user.

And let's say that I'm interested in storing, for each day, how much money User1 got from Income1, Income2, ... User2 from Income1, Income2... and so on. And even some day I'll aggregate all of this.

Still following me?

How should I model this?

First idea: Separate collections and separate documents

3 Collections : Income1, Income2, Income3. If an Income4 comes up, no problem, since I'll have to add some code, I can also create a new collection. Not an issue.

In each collection, the data for a user, with one document per user and per date, like this:

```
Income 1
{name:'user1', date:'2014-12-07',money:'24.32'}
{name:'user1', date:'2014-12-08',money:'14.20'}
{name:'user2', date:'2014-12-07',money:'0.00'}
{name:'user2', date:'2014-12-08',money:'0.00'}
{name:'user2', date:'2014-12-09',money:'10.00'}
{name:'user3', date:'2014-12-09',money:'124.32'}

Income 2
{name:'user1', date:'2014-12-05',money:'4.00'}
{name:'user2', date:'2014-12-06',money:'0.20'}
```

Second idea: Separate collections, and same document + embedded document

3 Collections as before. In each colection, the data for a user, with ONE document per user:

```
Income 1
{name:'user1', incomes: 
    [{date:'2014-12-07',money:'24.32'},{date:'2014-12-08',money:'14.20'}]}
{name:'user2', incomes:
    [{date:'2014-12-07',money:'0.00'},{date:'2014-12-08',money:'0.00'},{date:'2014-12-09',money:'10.00'}]}
{name:'user3', incomes:
    [{date:'2014-12-09',money:'124.32'}]}

Income 2
{name:'user1', incomes: [{date:'2014-12-05',money:'4.00'}]}
{name:'user2', incomes:[{date:'2014-12-06',money:'0.20'}]}
```

Third idea: SAme collection, and separate documents for everyghing.

```
{income_type:1,name:'user1', date:'2014-12-07',money:'24.32'}
{income_type:1,name:'user1', date:'2014-12-08',money:'14.20'}
{income_type:1,name:'user2', date:'2014-12-07',money:'0.00'}
{income_type:1,name:'user2', date:'2014-12-08',money:'0.00'}
{income_type:1,name:'user2', date:'2014-12-09',money:'10.00'}
{income_type:1,name:'user3', date:'2014-12-09',money:'124.32'}
{income_type:2,name:'user1', date:'2014-12-05',money:'4.00'}
{income_type:2,name:'user2', date:'2014-12-06',money:'0.20'}
```

These are some ideas. I'm sure there are others.

I will often have to query per user, on the most recent documents (i.e. with the most recent dates). I may from time to time need to aggregate information per week, month.... And, finally, I think I'll update the table from a cron running every night (to add the coresponding income for each income source and user)

Is this clear? I come from a relational database background (is it so obvious?) so maybe there is something I haven't even considered.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this point I would recommend the third idea. Rolling the data up per-user and / or per income stream is quite simple using the [aggregation pipeline](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/). Working with sub-documents is more pain than it's worth in my experience.

Comment: agreed. aggregating is very clear and simple with number 3. and specifically array subdocuments are a pain in the buttocks. you need $addtoset, $push and a bunch of other error prone ugly things.

Comment: Let alone the inevitable document migrations and alike.